# Disable publishing to PyPi with poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am a setting up Poetry in combination with Tox to automate builds and testing. The project I am working on however is private and I want to avoid anyone working on it accidentally publishing it to PyPi. I have initialized a project using `poetry init` and my assumption is that the resulting setup does not result in a viable package that can be published without any further setup to begin with. Is this correct?

How could I further configure poetry so that even if someone accidentally runs `poetry publish` in the future the package will not actually be published.

Comment: You cannot disable Poetry's default publish behavior currently. There is an open ticket on their GH about this and some related PRs that have not yet been merged. See: 

https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1537, https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-core/pull/27. I would not rely on whether or not `poetry init` will create a publishable package (if it doesn't now, how do you know it won't on the next update?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I know `poetry` does not support such straightforward option yet. But the workaround is possible:

```
[tool.poetry]
exclude = ["**"]
```

In TOML format: `*` denotes a single level wildcard, and `**` denotes all files in the given directory hierarchy.

`exclude = ["**"]` option prevents project files from getting into the package when `poetry build` is executed. It will show:

```
[ModuleOrPackageNotFound]
No file/folder found for package package_name
```

But nevertheless, `poetry` will create a `tar.gz` file and include three files in it: `pyproject.toml`, `setup.py`, and `PKG-INFO`. And it can be published

Answer (score 11):

Another option seems to be adding `"Private :: Do not Upload"` to `classifiers` in `pyproject.toml`.

```
[tool.poetry]
classifiers = ["Private :: Do not Upload"]
```

https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3692#issuecomment-789346308

Comment: [Official PyPI docs](https://pypi.org/classifiers/) say, "To prevent a package from being uploaded to PyPI, use the special "Private :: Do Not Upload" classifier. PyPI will always reject packages with classifiers beginning with "Private ::"."